# UIGetScreenImage will be reject now?

Tags: ios, capture

I know UIGetScreenImage is a private api, and in a period time can use in the appstore.

and later someone said can't use anymore.

So I ask here to make sure, Can use in my app and pass to Appstore?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Around a year ago, Apple started to run static analysis on submitted binaries during the App Store review process. Before that, access to private APIs will pass the review if the functionality itself wasn't too obvious to be caught by the reviewer.

Currently, reviewer uses automated methods to identify private APIs by their names. I recall reading somewhere that, not only aren't you allowed to call them, but also can't you use private API names in `Category` method names. I imagine because the scanning process is automated, you wouldn't have a shot to pass the review if you did use undocumented methods.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at this Apple tech note.  It shows how to "legally" do screenshots in UIKit where it ***will*** get accepted into the App Store:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1703/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010193

Comment: Great, but why does not the status bar get shot?

Comment: But alternative of CGImageRef UIGetScreenImage(void); does not gives 2x image when i take screen shot? For example the screen shot image returned from that private API is 640x1136 in retina display but other alternative code gives only 320x568 only

Comment: why do you (or your users) care about @2x when making screenshots, @iOSDeveloper?  You should only care about retina display and @2x (higher resolution) graphics when you are *creating* your apps, not when generating screenshots from them.  If you feel "`UIGetScreenImage`" has a flaw, you can always submit an enhancement request to Apple via http://bugreporter.apple.com

Comment: Dead Link can you refresh it maybe?

Answer (score 2):

They have been rejecting it again for a long time, since iOS 4 release in 2010 when they introduced AVFoundation framework which was a solution for all the camera frame capturing that `UIGetScreenImage()` was mostly used for before.

They offered two alternatives, one for camera frames ([Technical Q&A QA1702](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1702.html)) and one for UIKit elements ([Technical Q&A QA170](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1703.html) - the one that Michael mentioned), but neither of those is nearly enough usable for taking actual screenshots.

You can read the announcement at [developer forums](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1702.html) (iOS Developer Program account required).