# How to take Screen Shot of iPad Home screen programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, screenshot

i tried below code but it take only apps background screenshot, not iPad home screenshot...

```
CGImageRef screen = UIGetScreenImage();
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:screen];
CGImageRelease(screen);
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't take an image of the home screen from within your app. This would violate the sandbox principle.

Comment: Apple has opened up the API to allow applications to capture the screen contents, see this link                                                                http://www.tuaw.com/2009/12/15/apple-relents-and-is-now-allowing-uigetscreenimage-for-app-st/

Comment: The screen contents _while your app is in the foreground_. Not while it is in the background!

Comment: it is not mentioned..... look at this app it is on store              http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_1Nn0T0qVc

Comment: I don't see the connection. And your first link is massively outdated, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962342/uigetscreenimage-will-be-reject-now

Answer (score 0):

Its not permitted by Apple. there are possibilities of it if phone is jailbroken.